# solr does not import fields other than id

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am using Solr [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) module. Here is my config;

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              name="sql" 
              driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks2008;integratedSecurity=true;"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="Person"  dataSource="sql"
      pk="BusinessEntityID"
      query="select BusinessEntityID,FirstName,LastName FROM [Person].[Person]"
      deltaImportQuery="select BusinessEntityID,FirstName,LastName FROM [Person].[Person] WHERE id='${dih.delta.id}'"
      deltaQuery="SELECT BusinessEntityID FROM [Person].[Person] WHERE ModifiedDate > '${dih.last_index_time}'">
       <field column="BusinessEntityID" name="id"/>
       <field column="FirstName" name="firstname"/>       
       <field column="LastName" name="lastname"/>       
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

for some reason, only id field is importing but not the rest.

[image]

What would be the reason? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you mention the other fields in schema.xml? could you please share the schema.xml?

Comment: Something like this ...<field name="id"        type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="firstname"     type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="lastname"  type="string"    indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti oh, maybe that is what I am missing, since I am pretty new to solr, I did not introduce any schema configuration yet. Let me try this out, and please include your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have missed the below entries in the `schema.xml` file

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/> 
<field name="firstname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="lastname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Here type for `id` can be `int`. Just check what you want.

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Id and unique field is Proper.
I was facing same issue, change Pk and unique field name and it's working fine.